# mod_rewrite slash snafu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I know this question has been asked 20 other times and 20 different ways but after all of my researching I still can't seem to figure this out.  My setup works great until I type in a URL with a trailing slash and then I get 404 errors.  For example, when I type in the URL `mydomain.com/first` and hit enter, it works fine.  When I type in `mydomain.com/first/` and hit enter, it works fine then too.  But then, if I type in `mydomain.com/second` it sends me to `mydomain.com/first/second` and throws a 404 error.

Here is my entire htaccess page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

My index page:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); // Define the root directory for use in includes 
require_once (ROOT_DIR . 'library/bootstrap.php');

$url = strtolower($_GET['url']);

include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/headerView.php');

switch($url)
{
    case "first": include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/firstPageView.php');
        break;
    case "second": include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/secondPageView.php');
        break;
    default: include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/homeView.php');
} 

include 'views/footerView.php';
?>
```

And the default homeView template:

```
<p>This is the home page.</p>
<p>To the first page. <a href="first">First Page</a></p>
<p>To the second page. <a href="second">Second Page</a></p>
```

I would think that since the slash is optional and not part of the back reference, that the slash would be left off the URL after the page load but in my above example, its clearly not.  Any advice would be most appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Last line of your htaccess : have you really `/IfModule>` or this is only a copy/paste error ?

Comment: I can't see how going to `mydomain.com/secondPage` can result in getting served `/firstPage/secondPage`

Comment: @samsamX Yes, that was a typo.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Same as Jon Lin, I don't see anything which can redirect your query. Try to add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On`. Are you sure you don't have any other rewrite rules somewhere ?

Comment: @samsamX No, that's my only .htaccess file and just to clarify, I have to type in mydomain.com/first/ hit enter and then while still on that page with the URL saying mydomian.com/first/, type in mydomain.com/second to get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /myProject/index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You need to put in the / in front of index.php.

Otherwise Apache will look for the index.php file in your current directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that didn't seem to work.  It actually made it so when I go to mydomain.com/first I get a 404.  Would it help to know that my .htaccess file is in the same folder with my index.php file?

Comment: Which folders are they in? index.php and .htaccess should both be located directly in the htdocs folder for this solution to work

Comment: They're in my project sub folder which is directly inside htdocs.  For example: htdocs>myProject>index.php

Comment: Then use /myProject/index.php for the second part of the Rewrite Rule (I edited the answer above)

Comment: Well, that seemed to fix the issue when I type in the URLs but my links still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]*)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

your mod_rewrite config is ok, the problem is on the client.  if current path is `/foo/first`, `<a href="second"/>` will lead to `/foo/second`.  if it's `/foo/first/`, the same `<a href/>` will lead to `/foo/first/second`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens.  While at /foo/first/ clicking a link with <a href="second"> will take me to /foo/first/second which doesn't exist.  My problem is how to fix that?  Even if I change href="second" to href="index.php?url=second I get the same problem only now the address bar says /foo/first/index.php?url=second...  I'm guessing it has something to do with Apache treating /foo/first/ as a directory and not as a page.  Any ideas?

Comment: change it to `<a href="/foo/second"/>`.